# Sending email using GMail in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to open email sending form of Gmail directly on button click but this always shows a list of options for sending email.

I am doing this for opening GMail form:

```
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent( android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            String[] recipients = new String[]{"" , "" ,};
            emailIntent.putExtra( android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
            emailIntent.putExtra( android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "This is my text" );
            emailIntent.putExtra( android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
            emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
            startActivity( Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send Email" ));
```

but this is not opening GMail form. What can i do for opening GMail form please help.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The reason you are seeing a list of options is because you are using `Intent.createChooser(...)`. In your case, this will always create a list of apps which can handle `ACTION_SEND` for the mime-type `message/rfc822`. There's no way of explicitly telling it to use GMail. You could try it without `createChooser(...)` and, (if you are lucky) the user may have set GMail as their default mail app. IF you are lucky that is. If they set their default to anothe mail app it will use that instead. I'm not actually sure it's possible to do what you want. Certainly not with `createChooser(...)`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use something on the lines

```
public void sendGmail(Activity activity, String subject, String text) {
    Intent gmailIntent = new Intent();
    gmailIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");
    gmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    gmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
    try {
      activity.startActivity(gmailIntent);
    } catch(ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
      // handle error
    }
}
```

Comment: it gives `null pointer exception` on  this `activity.startActivity(gmailIntent);` line.

Comment: make sure u are passing current activity object, you can also add this method inside your activity class and call startActivity(gmailIntent); directly

Comment: thanks now this working fine. i am passing `getParent()` before it and this was crash my application.

Comment: Is there any possibility to attach a file?

Comment: To avoid NullPointerException or handling exceptions you have to verify if that intent can be handled using gmailIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())