# How to skip the chooser dialog for sending mail in android

Tags: android, email, gmail, sendmail

I'm getting the pop-up for choosing the email client (Gmail, EMail, etc.), but I want to skip it and instead send it directly through GMail.

```
protected void sendEmail() {        
   String[] recipients = { recieverId.getText().toString() };
   Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND, Uri.parse("mailto:"));

   email.setType("message/rfc822");

   email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
   email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, mailSubject.getText().toString());
   email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mailBody.getText().toString());

   try {
      startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email,
         "Choose an email client from..."));
   } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
         "No email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply omit `createChooser` and hardcode Gmail intent, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9708399/1889459):

```
public void sendGmail(Activity activity, String subject, String text) {
    Intent gmailIntent = new Intent();
    gmailIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");
    gmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    gmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
    try {
      activity.startActivity(gmailIntent);
    } catch(ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
      // handle error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent();
    emailIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");// Package Name, Class Name
    emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); 
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain"); 
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "Your Sender Mail ID"); 
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your Subject"); 
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body of the Email "); 
    startActivity(emailIntent);
}

    You can get the Package name via adb shell Command:
    pm list packages -f
```

Answer (score 0):

```
emailIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");// Package Name, Class Name
```

Setting class name in intent worked for me. No need to add chooser. For sending email through your office mailclient you can add From (for intent) or select from the list of mail ids from gmail account compose section (From).