# How to send mail without using the native Gmail app in android?

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I am able to retrieve the email id of the users using the Account Manager in my code. But I am unable to get the password as it throws Security Exception. What should I do?

Is there anyway to launch the native Gmail app in the background so that when the user clicks on the send button of the custom interface, the data should be transferred using the native app without the user realizing it?

Comment: You can use JavaMail API !!

Comment: Please check -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a/2033124#2033124

Comment: i am using JavaMail API . But i don't want users to explicitly type the password. i wish to extract the password from their accounts which they have synced in the phone. I am using Account Manager to retrieve the synced  email id . But i don't know how to retrieve the password. If i cannot retrieve the password then how can I send the mail?

Comment: Please check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707739/sending-email-using-gmail-in-android

Comment: @Raunak: I guess It's hack :) I think it is not possible or allowed!!

Comment: @AndiGeeky : Okay :)

Comment: @Cade: This will pass an intent to the native Gmail app. I have no issues in sending messages from the Gmail app. Gmail app may run in background but I don't want the users to feel that the message has been sent from the native Gmail app. Is there a way by which I can connect the Send button in my customized layout to the send button in the Gmail app?